# Detecting intersection of two WGS84 lines

Tags: line, coordinates, intersection, geodetic

How do you detect intersection of two WGS84 lines given the information below known.

RedLine: `latStart0, lonStart0, latEnd0, lonEnd0`

BlueLine: `latStart1, lonStart1, latEnd1, lonEnd1`

[image: intersection]

Comment: Which software are you working with? What have you tried?

Comment: This is not a software specific question, i just want to know the technique behind

Comment: It's a partial differential equation only solvable through computational means. You want to be using (validated) software for this.